# Profile Metadata Missing

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, metadata

I am retrieving Profiles and custom fields with Package.xml, But there are fields permission missing.

```
*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
      
        <members>Admin</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
       
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <members>Account</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    
</types>
</package>*
```

And Metadata of profile retrieve is like:

```
 <custom>false</custom>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.AccountNumber</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.AccountSource</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.Account_Rating__c</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>true</editable>
        <field>Account.Account_Type__c</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
```

Here field Visibility Permissions are Missing

Comment: How are they missing? Which ones are missing?

Comment: Field visibility permission is missing here@sfdcfox

Comment: 'visibility' is the same as 'readable'; it depends on the API version of the metadata request.

Comment: Are you looking for fields on _other_ objects? Please [edit] your post to provide a clear example of what you think should be included.

Comment: Actually When I deploy this metadata in another org with profiles, then fields are not visible there, I need to do check visibility for each field manually...as far I know profile metadata include visibility permission so that after deployment I don't have to do it manually that what my concern is